# the hover dropdown menu does not position itself the right place

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am writing a new web page, and I am stuck In the navbar specify the responsive part...

when I zoom out the web page, the dropdown menu does not align itself with the parent link

[image: 1024px]

[image]

Is that normal? I tried to use rem and percentage units in the left CSS property for the dropdown `ul` but that didn't work,, Is there a way to fix it or I have to put the navbar into a container and center it?

my code:

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box
}

body, html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
}

nav {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 5rem 1fr;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: #000000;
}

.logo, .menu {
    margin-left: 2rem;
}

.logo h1 {
    color: #FFF;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    font-weight: 600;
    letter-spacing: 5px;
}

.menu {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}

.menu li {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #808080;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    list-style: none;
    font-size: .9rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    padding: .4rem .4rem;
}

.menu .active {
    color: #FFF;
}

.menu ul {
    width: 20%;
    height: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    left: 30%;
    top: 25px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    z-index: 1;
    padding: 10px 0;
    background: #FFF;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 30px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    transition: all .5s ease;
}

.menu > li:nth-of-type(4) > a {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #808080;
}

.menu > li:nth-of-type(4) > a::after, .menu ul:before {
    display: inline-block;
    font-style: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    text-rendering: auto;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
}

.menu ul:before {
    font-weight: 900;
    position: absolute;
    top: -15px;
    left: 25px;
    content: "\f0d8";
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 25px;
}

.menu > li:nth-of-type(4) > a::after {
    font-weight: 900;
    padding-left: 5px;
    content: "\f0d7";
}

.menu ul li {
    display: none;
    padding: 1rem 0;
    text-indent: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: .5s all ease-out;
}

.menu ul li a {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    text-transform: capitalize;
}

.menu ul li:hover {
    background-color: #e74208;
}

.menu ul li:hover a {
    color: #fff;
}

.menu li:nth-of-type(4):hover ul {
    height: auto;
    opacity: 1;
}

.menu li:nth-of-type(4):hover ul li {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav>
            <div class="logo"><!-- Logo -->
                <h1>Hexa</h1>
            </div>
            <ul class="menu"><!-- Nav Menu -->
                <li class="active">Home</li>
                <li>About</li>
                <li>Projects</li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Parent Link</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Architectural Design</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Interior</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Building</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>Blog</li>
                <li>Contact</li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

Comment: .menu ul {
    left: 20%;
    top: 42px;
}

Comment: as Filipe said, I had to position the ul menu absolutely to the parent list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To position your dropdown menu you should add a position relative to is parent li. You are positioning the dropdown absolutely in relation to your .menu

```
.menu > li:nth-of-type(4) {
    position: relative;
}
```